# Vlaning on WNR3500L

Tags: openwrt, vlan

When I try connecting to my wireless network it attempts to connect then gives up.

There's something strange going on with the mac's. The eternet switch and all the vlan interfaces have a mac 00:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.

```
config 'switch' 'eth0'
        option 'vlan0' '2 3 4 8*'
        option 'vlan1' '0 8'
        option 'vlan2' '1 8'

config 'interface' 'loopback'
        option 'ifname' 'lo'
        option 'proto' 'static'
        option 'ipaddr' '127.0.0.1'
        option 'netmask' '255.0.0.0'

config 'interface' 'lan'
        option 'type' 'bridge'
        option 'ifname' 'eth0.1'
        option 'proto' 'static'
        option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
        option 'ipaddr' '192.168.2.1'
        option 'ip6addr' ''
        option 'gateway' '192.168.1.253'
        option 'ip6gw' ''
        option 'dns' ''

config 'interface' 'wan'                    
        option 'ifname' 'eth0'              
        option 'proto' 'dhcp'               
        option 'ipaddr' '192.168.1.8'       
        option 'ip6addr' ''                 
        option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'    
        option 'gateway' '192.168.1.253'    
        option 'ip6gw' ''                   
        option 'dns' '192.168.1.253'        

config 'interface' 'dmz'                    
       option 'ifname' 'eth0.2'             
       option 'proto' 'static'              
       option 'ipaddr' '192.168.0.1'        
       option 'netmask' '255.255.255.0'
```

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated! When I try setting the mac using macaddr it does nothing. It works perfectly fine when I turn the authentication off.  I've also discovered that when wpa2 is switched on I don't receive a association reply from ap.

thats my hostapd.conf

```
interface=eth1
driver=broadcom
bridge=br-lan
ssid=O2BB3
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=prettywoman
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

Btw that password is only temporary while am testing.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this using dd-wrt. At the time of this posting it's nesscessary to manually configure the vlans using nvram because the web interface gui doesn't actually do anything. It's just a place holder hence there's no code attached

Comment: I'd be really interested in knowing whether one can get VLANs working on the WNR3500L using Tomato in the same way, as there seems to be support in the kernel.

Comment: I was able to restore a broken vlan configuration on my WNR3500L, running LEDE 17.01.4, by erasing the nvram. I previously had DD-WRT installed, and it had left the nvram in a bad state, which I wasn't able to fix directly in OpenWRT. Instead, erasing the nvram worked: `mtd erase nvram`